# Submission Problems for iOS

Tags: ios4, app-store-connect, application-loader

I'm trying to submit an app to the app store via the Application Loader but am getting some pretty upsetting errors:

1) bundle identifier CM.paradisebeats differs from reserved bundle identifer ...
   -I changed this in the plist file to the correct one, saved and recompressed but no luck

2) there is no co_design_wrapper executable. Please reinstall the Xcode developer tools
   -Yeah no way. What does this mean?

3) iPhone/iPod Touch: application executable is missing a required architecture. At least one of the following architecture(s) must be present: armv6
   -Went to change this in the Architecture section of Build Settings. It is set to Standard (armv7) and has no other options except to add my own. There is not Standard (armv6, armv7) option. Could this be because I may or may not be running XCode 4.2?

Hoping to get this out soon so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't submit applications for the App Store built with a beta of Xcode. Since you say you "may or may not be running Xcode 4.2", I think you're implying that you're using the beta. In that case, the error message you so colourfully complained about -- "Please reinstall the Xcode developer tools" -- is entirely correct.

Comment: So I have to uninstall the beta and reinstall...what? Should I look for a random 4.0.2 DMG laying around my laptop or redownload those numerous GBs from the Mac App Store?

Comment: @Chris I'd look for random .dmg files first

Comment: I searched but they are gone. Also called Apple and they were thoroughly unhelpful. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Chris uh... download the older SDK already? And hopefully you read the Readme and didn't install the beta firmware image on your only device

Comment: I downloaded and installed 4.0.2 but now XCode opens and immediately crashes. Why is this?